# Cogs are loaded but the functions don't work (discord.py)

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I've got a Problem. I am writing a discord Bot with "Discord.py". I'm using "Python 3.8.1" on my "Raspberry Pi 3B".

I have got a "load" and a "unload" function in my main file. They do work as they should. 
But I have Cogs, for example the easies one: "ping".
I can load "ping", but the command doesn't work (in every Cog):
*"Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not found"*

I have no Idea where the Problem could be. The Code seems to be right - according to others. I watched YouTube Videos on it, but no answer...
I will try to use another python version for example "3.7.x"...

My bot.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import os


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/")



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'\n\nBot is ready!\nName: {client.user.name}\nID: {client.user.id}\n      ---------\n')

    return


@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}') #loads the extension in the "cogs" folder
    await ctx.send(f'Loaded "{extension}"')
    print(f'Loaded "{extension}"')

    return


@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}') #unloads the extension in the "cogs" folder
    await ctx.send(f'Unloaded "{extension}"')
    print(f'Unoaded "{extension}"')

    return



print('\n')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'): #loads all files (*.py)
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}') #loads the file without ".py" for example: cogs.ping
        print(f'Loaded {filename[:-3]}')


client.run('MY TOKEN')
```

My ping.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


        @commands.command()
        async def ping(self, ctx):
            await ctx.send(f'pong!\n{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')

        return



def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Ping(client))
```

Do you find any mistake??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the function `ping` in the class's scope, not inside the constructor.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx): # This was inside '__init__' before
        await ctx.send(f'pong!\n{round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms')
        return


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Ping(client))
```

Comment: It worked!
But i had to write `await ctx.send(f'pong!\n{round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms')` ...